# Cómo puedo enviar mail desde Java con mi servidor de correo electronico

Tags: java, email, smtp, imap

Utilizo la siguiente clave para enviar el mensaje, pero obtengo una excepción:

```
public class EmailSenderService {

  public static boolean enviarMensaje(final String remitente, final String claveRemitente, String destinatario, String asunto, String mensaje) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.solincosta.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "995");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(remitente, claveRemitente);
        }
    });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(remitente));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(destinatario));
        message.setSubject(asunto);
        message.setText(mensaje);

        Transport.send(message);

        return true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("EXCEPCION: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

He probado con varios servidores de correo y me ocurre lo mismo, al llamar al método obtengo esta excepción:

> EXCEPCION: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.solincosta.com, port:
>   995, response: -1 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to
>   SMTP host: mail.solincosta.com, port: 995, response: -1
>   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1949)
>   at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
>   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
>   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
>   at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
>   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
>   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
>   at util.EmailSenderService.enviarMensaje(EmailSenderService.java:40)
>   at pruebas.menu.main(menu.java:36)

Comment: `javax.mail.Authenticator` significa que estás usando [JavaMail](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) verdad?